# Parsing numbers in FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I've started learning FParsec. It has a very flexible way to parse numbers; I can provide a set of number formats I want to use:

```
type Number =
    | Numeral of int
    | Decimal of float
    | Hexadecimal of int
    | Binary of int

let numberFormat = NumberLiteralOptions.AllowFraction
                   ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowHexadecimal
                   ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowBinary

let pnumber = 
    numberLiteral numberFormat "number"
    |>> fun num -> if num.IsHexadecimal then Hexadecimal (int num.String)
                   elif num.IsBinary then Binary (int num.String)
                   elif num.IsInteger then Numeral (int num.String)
                   else Decimal (float num.String)
```

However, the language I'm trying to parse is a bit strange. A number could be numeral (non-negative `int`), decimal (non-negative `float`), hexadecimal (with prefix `#x`) or binary (with prefix `#b`):

```
numeral: 0, 2
decimal: 0.2, 2.0
hexadecimal: #xA04, #x611ff
binary: #b100, #b001
```

Right now I have to do parsing twice by substituting `#` by `0` (if necessary) to make use of `pnumber`:

```
let number: Parser<_, unit> =  
    let isDotOrDigit c = isDigit c || c = '.'
    let numOrDec = many1Satisfy2 isDigit isDotOrDigit 
    let hexOrBin = skipChar '#' >>. manyChars (letter <|> digit) |>> sprintf "0%s"
    let str = spaces >>. numOrDec <|> hexOrBin
    str |>> fun s -> match run pnumber s with
                     | Success(result, _, _)   -> result
                     | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> failwith errorMsg
```

What is a better way of parsing in this case? Or how can I alter FParsec's `CharStream` to be able to make conditional parsing easier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parsing numbers can be pretty messy if you want to generate good error messages and properly check for overflows.

The following is a simple FParsec implementation of your number parser:

```
let numeralOrDecimal : Parser<_, unit> =
    // note: doesn't parse a float exponent suffix
    numberLiteral NumberLiteralOptions.AllowFraction "number" 
    |>> fun num -> 
            // raises an exception on overflow
            if num.IsInteger then Numeral(int num.String)
            else Decimal(float num.String)

let hexNumber =    
    pstring "#x" >>. many1SatisfyL isHex "hex digit"
    |>> fun hexStr -> 
            // raises an exception on overflow
            Hexadecimal(System.Convert.ToInt32(hexStr, 16)) 

let binaryNumber =    
    pstring "#b" >>. many1SatisfyL (fun c -> c = '0' || c = '1') "binary digit"
    |>> fun hexStr -> 
            // raises an exception on overflow
            Binary(System.Convert.ToInt32(hexStr, 2))


let number =
    choiceL [numeralOrDecimal
             hexNumber
             binaryNumber]
            "number literal"
```

Generating good error messages on overflows would complicate this implementation a bit, as you would ideally also need to backtrack after the error, so that the error position ends up at the start of the number literal (see the [numberLiteral](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.numberLiteral) docs for an example).

A simple way to gracefully handle possible overflow exception is to use a little exception handling combinator like the following:

```
let mayThrow (p: Parser<'t,'u>) : Parser<'t,'u> =
    fun stream ->
        let state = stream.State        
        try 
            p stream
        with e -> // catching all exceptions is somewhat dangerous
            stream.BacktrackTo(state)
            Reply(FatalError, messageError e.Message)
```

You could then write

```
let number = mayThrow (choiceL [...] "number literal")
```

I'm not sure what you meant to say with "alter FParsec's `CharStream` to be able to make conditional parsing easier", but the following sample demonstrates how you could write a low-level implementation that only uses the `CharStream` methods directly.

```
type NumberStyles = System.Globalization.NumberStyles
let invariantCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

let number: Parser<Number, unit> =
  let expectedNumber = expected "number"
  let inline isBinary c = c = '0' || c = '1'
  let inline hex2int c = (int c &&& 15) + (int c >>> 6)*9

  let hexStringToInt (str: string) = // does no argument or overflow checking        
      let mutable n = 0
      for c in str do
          n <- n*16 + hex2int c
      n    

  let binStringToInt (str: string) = // does no argument or overflow checking
      let mutable n = 0
      for c in str do
          n <- n*2 + (int c - int '0')
      n

  let findIndexOfFirstNonNull (str: string) =
      let mutable i = 0
      while i < str.Length && str.[i] = '0' do
          i <- i + 1
      i

  let isHexFun = id isHex // tricks the compiler into caching the function object
  let isDigitFun = id isDigit
  let isBinaryFun = id isBinary

  fun stream ->
    let start = stream.IndexToken
    let cs = stream.Peek2()        
    match cs.Char0, cs.Char1 with
    | '#', 'x' ->
        stream.Skip(2)
        let str = stream.ReadCharsOrNewlinesWhile(isHexFun, false)
        if str.Length <> 0 then
            let i = findIndexOfFirstNonNull str
            let length = str.Length - i
            if length < 8 || (length = 8 && str.[i] <= '7') then
                Reply(Hexadecimal(hexStringToInt str))
            else
                stream.Seek(start)
                Reply(Error, messageError "hex number literal is too large for 32-bit int")
        else 
            Reply(Error, expected "hex digit")

    | '#', 'b' ->
        stream.Skip(2)
        let str = stream.ReadCharsOrNewlinesWhile(isBinaryFun, false)
        if str.Length <> 0 then
            let i = findIndexOfFirstNonNull str
            let length = str.Length - i
            if length < 32 then 
                Reply(Binary(binStringToInt str))
            else
                stream.Seek(start)
                Reply(Error, messageError "binary number literal is too large for 32-bit int")
        else 
            Reply(Error, expected "binary digit")

    | c, _ ->
        if not (isDigit c) then Reply(Error, expectedNumber)
        else
            stream.SkipCharsOrNewlinesWhile(isDigitFun) |> ignore
            if stream.Skip('.') then
                let n2 = stream.SkipCharsOrNewlinesWhile(isDigitFun)
                if n2 <> 0 then
                    // we don't parse any exponent, as in the other example
                    let mutable result = 0.
                    if System.Double.TryParse(stream.ReadFrom(start), 
                                              NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                                              invariantCulture, 
                                              &result)
                    then Reply(Decimal(result))
                    else 
                        stream.Seek(start)
                        Reply(Error, messageError "decimal literal is larger than System.Double.MaxValue")                    
                else 
                    Reply(Error, expected "digit")
            else
               let decimalString = stream.ReadFrom(start)
               let mutable result = 0
               if System.Int32.TryParse(stream.ReadFrom(start),
                                        NumberStyles.None,
                                        invariantCulture,
                                        &result)
               then Reply(Numeral(result))
               else 
                   stream.Seek(start)
                   Reply(Error, messageError "decimal number literal is too large for 32-bit int")
```

While this implementation parses hex and binary numbers without the help of system methods, it eventually delegates the parsing of decimal numbers to the Int32.TryParse and Double.TryParse methods.

As I said: it's messy.

Comment: +1, thanks for the fast response, Stephan. By "alter FParsec's CharStream...", I meant a low level manipulation of `CharStream`. I will go for the first approach, simple and understandable. BTW, what is the cost of using combinators with labels? Does it cost a lot if I use labels everywhere in the parser?

Comment: I've just added a comment on how one could deal with overflow exceptions in the first version more gracefully. Regarding the labels: it depends. `choiceL` is actually  faster than `choice`, because it doesn't have to collect the individual error messages. In general the overhead of `<?>` and similar combinators should be hardly measurable in non-trivial applications. And if you actually spot a performance issue in an FParsec parser, there are always ways to make it faster...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just one minor point, `skipString` should be preferred to `pstring` in this case, right?

Comment: There's no performance difference, as both parsers have to do no work to create the result value (which in both cases is a reference type constant). Hence, it's only a question of taste.